# How to make Jest mocked function toHaveBeenCalledTimes has a fresh count for each test suite?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

When I assert the number of time the mocked function been called the imported mocked function always return the combined number of invocations.

For example, the first test suite has a function called the mocked function `import { get } from 'axios'` once and the expected `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` is `1`. However, the second test suite, the function called `get` again and `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` is `2` instead of `1`.

How to make the mocked function `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` return a refresh count for each test suit?

```
describe('fetchAData', () => {
    it('should return the right A data response', (done) => {
        const sampleResponse = { data: dataASample };

        get.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
            return Promise.resolve(sampleResponse);
        });

        fetchAData().then(() => {
            expect(get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

            done();
        });
    });
});

describe('fetchBData', () => {
    it('should return the right B data response', (done) => {
        const sampleResponse = { data: dataBSample };

        get.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
            return Promise.resolve(sampleResponse);
        });

        fetchBData().then(() => {
            expect(get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // -> Return `2`
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mockFn.mockReset()` just did the trick, https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreset

> Does everything that mockFn.mockClear() does, and also removes any mocked return values or implementations.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    get.mockReset();
});
```

Comment: Just in case anyone needs, `jest.resetAllMocks()` does the same for all mock functions.